# Why $\sum|n^ka_n|<\infty$ implies $f \in C^k$ where $a_n$ is the $n-th$ Fourier coefficient of $f$

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I want to know why $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|n^ka_n|<\infty$$ implies $f \in C^k$
where $a_n$ is the $nth$ Fourier coefficient of $f$.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is the sum in $k$? I think it should be in $n$. Assuming this is the case: do you know how to prove that if the Fourier series of a function is absolute convergent then the function is continuos ?

Comment: @Marco you are right, I made correction.

Comment: Maybe check out [this book](https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~picard/SMC/didattica/materiali_did/Anal.Armon./Katznelson/Katznelson.pdf): "Introduction to Harmonic Analysis" by Katznelson. In particular, see Theorem 4.3 and its remark (bottom of page 24 of the book).